# File could not be uploaded in laravel although all the tags and functions are seemed okay

Tags: php, laravel

First question asked in this forum.
I have watched many tutorials on file uploading in laravel, did exactly what they did but file is not uploading. It would be great of you could help me.I am posting all the relevant codes for this.

Here is my html code for taking file input and other inputs

```
    <div id="form" >

    <div id="select" style="font-size:20px;">

    {{ Form::open(['route' => 'gpa.science'])}}


    <div id="youtubelink" style="font-size:20px;">
    <p>শিরোনাম :</p>
    <h22 >  {{ Form::textarea('title', null, ['size' => '70x1']) }} </h22>  
    </div>

    </br>

    <div id="youtubelink" style="font-size:20px;">
    <p>ইউটিউব ভিডিও লিঙ্ক :</p>
    <h22 >  {{ Form::textarea('videokey', null, ['size' => '70x1']) }} </h22>   
    </div>  

        </br>


    <div>
    <form action="" name="filea">
    <input type="file" name="filea" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="hidden" value="{{ csrf_token() }}" name="_token">
    </div>
    </form>


    <div class="input-filed">
            {{ Form::submit('Submit', ['class'=>'btn btn-primary right'])}}

  {{ Form::close()}}
        </div>
```

Here is my route

```
Route::post('/blog1', ['as'=>'gpa.science', 'uses' => 'PageController@blogafter']);
```

Now after submit button this will go to this PageController.
PageController Code:

```
<?php    namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use DB; 
use App\Quotation;  
use Input;  
use Illuminate\Http\Request; 
use App\Filename;  use Storage;  
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\File; 
use Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile;

class PageController extends Controller {

  public function blogafter(Request $request){

            //return $request->all();
            if($request->hasFile('filea'))
     {
          dd('Got the file');
     }

     dd('No file');

            return view('blogafter');
        } }
```

Now the problem is it does not get any file. Always shows no file.If I do `$request->all();` it returns

```
 videokey   null
 filea  "working.sql"
```

Now can anyone tell me what is wrong in my code? Why I can not upload files. I am using laravel 5.4.36 and php version 5.6.31

Comment: Check your php.ini has a high enough `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size`, this is most likely the issue.

Comment: both edited to 1024M

Comment: Nice question, too ;-) ... have fun upvoting now ;-) x 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

`{{ Form::open(['route' => 'gpa.science']) }}`

to

`{{ Form::open(['route' => 'gpa.science', 'files' => true]) }}`

This will add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` to the form, which is required to upload files to PHP.

Comment: Thanks for your kind help. I did it. actually 'files' => true was one of the main key I was missing.

Comment: Feel free to accept & upvote the answer if I was able to help.

Answer (score 3):

You have typo in your form which is missing `enctype="multipart/form-data"`

```
    <form action="" name="filea" method="post"  enctype="multipart/form-data" >
```

Add
    `{{ Form::open(['route' => 'gpa.science', 'files'=> true])}}`

Hope this helps.

Comment: @Yunus no dear you have two form in your code and one submit. please recheck

Comment: I have done both methods. Just kept the input method and removed form tag. But no luck brothers.

Comment: Alhamdulillah.. Got it. Thanks dude. I have removed one form tag , put 'files' => true and that's it.

Comment: @Yunus i am glad it helped you.